# Plot prediction for covariates from GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, prediction

I have run GLMs and got my final model that fits my data. Now I would like to plot each of my important covariate versus the predicted values. I would like to keep all the other covariates of the model constant and have one covariate that varies and plot it. My goal is to obtain a line with confidence intervals on which I can see the predicted value for a certain value of my covariate. I have a really clear idea of the graph I want but I have no idea how to plot it in R. Any suggestions? 
Thank you,

Comment: Something like `mmps` in package `car`? Or perhaps the `effects` package?

Comment: Thank you so much! The effects package is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: However, I have been trying to change my x-axis as it gives negative values to my covariate that does not take negative values. I have tried to set up the effect using xlevels=list(Cov1=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)) but it does not change my graph. Do you know how to modify that?

Comment: No, sorry; I've only used it for some very basic plots.